# Including Google Analytics in Swift Bridging Header

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, google-analytics

This has actually been driving me crazy.

I've been following the instructions [on the Google Developer's site](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift) (which doesn't actually have an import line, but if you inspect the element you can kinda notice that someone messed up and it's supposed to be `#import <Google/Analytics.h>`)

But Xcode just refuses to find the Google Analytics, while it imports the other header in my bridging header perfectly alright (e.g. it reads the file fine, but only does one of the imports).

My file looks like this:

```
#import <workinglibrary.h>
#import <Google/Analytics.h> // this doesn't work!
```

I've tried every variation of `<Analytics.h>` or `"Google/Analytics.h"` and so on. My header search paths looks fine too:

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/Google"
"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/Google/Google"
"${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/GoogleAnalytics"
...
```

Final caveat: I'm not sure (since Xcode doesn't fully build when I do this), but I *think* that Xcode properly imports the `Analytics.h` file if I comment out the `#import <workinglibrary.h>` statement (at least, I can Apple + Click analytics functions in other files to get to their declaration).

EDIT: just kidding that last bit isn't true

Comment: Did you found the answer? I'm on the same problem.

Comment: I forget the specifics, but I think that my main app target actually had no trouble finding Google Analytics, but one of my specs wasn't importing it properly. There's a bunch of issues with Google Analytics right now with iOS though -- e.g. you'll run into issues if you need to `use_frameworks!` at all. (https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=609)

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. This has been fixed in cocoapods 0.38.2

To update use: `gem install cocoapods`

You can use_frameworks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like for the latest stable Swift/XCode/Cocoapods/GA it needs putting `#import <GoogleAnalytics/GAI.h>` into bridging header